# Variable Internationalization(I18n) looks ups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, internationalization

I have a before_save validation in my model

`:before_save, :check_confirmations
def check_confirmations
  self.confirmations[:providers] = I18n.t('enough')
end`

However, the validation message that I want to show is dependent upon data that is inside of the view and controller, and this data is inaccessible inside/to the model.

Is there anyway inside of the controller I can specify which version of the internationalization to use?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you mean by version. We can set locale on controller

> I18n.locale = params[:locale]

Typically this set in application controller but can be overridden as well. You can look here for more details. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html